# Android Receiver for wifi web login

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a wifi whit web autentication ej:https://weblogin/login
To login it show a web explorer dialog to select with what browser i do the login 
I want to made an app that can be select when i conect to a wifi whit captive portal web login handles the login
and set as default for this action but no have any idea what i can googleit for that even And want know if is posible to do of course

### thanks

### UPDATE

What i refer is  ACTION_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_SIGN_IN of ConnectivityManager
but is added in anroid M API and I want for older androids.

Comment: I want a equivalent of android.net.conn.CAPTIVE_PORTAL for olders androids